# R - moving window comparison with datasets of unequal size

Tags: r, math, comparison, dataframe, zoo

I need to compare a large set of values to a small set and find the minimum difference between the two.  Maybe this is “moving window” comparison?  I’ve looked at several time series packages but can’t find (or recognize) a function that compares data sets of different sizes.  Text example below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    ----------1st comparison-----------

    Time     S1     S2     Diff     Mean Diff
    1        1.3    1.2    0.1
    2        1.7    1.6    0.1      0.10
    3        1.2     
    4        1.6

    ----------2nd comparison------------

    1        1.3    
    2        1.7    1.2    0.5
    3        1.2    1.6   -0.4      0.05
    4        1.6

    ----------3rd comparison------------     

    1        1.3     
    2        1.7
    3        1.2    1.2    0.0
    4        1.6    1.6    0.0      0.00     <- minimum difference
```

Comment: Maybe this is something specific to your domain, but I find the formulation of your task somewhat confusing. Find the difference between the large and the small set. If it is what you call the moving windows, then it is well implemented in the answer, but is that really what you need? If these are time series, what meaning does it have to move values across timeline? It seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
require(zoo)
S1 <- c(1.3,1.7,1.2,1.6)
S2 <- c(1.2,1.6)
```

We can use rollapply to apply a function rolling along a vector. The width is set at the size of the smaller comparison vector. We then use an anonymous function to pass the values from our large vector, S1, as the variable `x` from which we then subtract the values from the small vector and take the mean. We can then use `min` to return the smallest value:

```
> min( rollapply( S1 , width = 2 , function(x) mean(x-S2) ) )
[1] 0
```

It's hard to make it more generalisable without the structure of your data

Comment: Great! If it answered the question you may want to consider pressing the green check next to the answer that way this question can be moved off the unanswered questions stack. See the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for more info on the way SO works. Cheers!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Actually I have re-read the question and agree. It could be simplifeid as you suggest. And even further. I will *rollforward* to your edit